# React-Native method hangs and does not throw an error

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am using the react-native-fs module, however my app seems to be freezing on it. I have the following piece of code in one of my React-Native methods:

```
console.log("One")
await RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: 'http://example.com/data/blah.zip',
    toFile: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/userdata/blah.zip",
}).promise
console.log("Two")
```

"One" is echoed to the console, but "Two" never gets echoed.  There is no error thrown. The URL does in fact exist and the RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + /userdata directory does exist.

What am I doing wrong? Why is no error thrown? Why is it hanging at this point?

**Update**

Unfortunately, because it only seems to happen sometimes it is hard to diagnose or to produce a smaller test. What I've had to do is when this happens I have to shut down the react-native command prompt node window and rerun `react-native run-android`. Once I do that it proceeds perfectly.

Comment: Do you need a .then clause after promise?

RNFS.downloadFile({fromUrl:url, toFile: path}).promise.then(res => {
  console.log('1.5')
});

Comment: @Dan, I am using await instead. But even if I try a .then instead of await it still hangs at the same spot.

Comment: Hmmm, for whatever reason this error seems to be intermittent. Sometimes it seems to work and other times it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could the issue be from the server providing the .zip? Maybe this can be narrowed downed further if you try downloading only from a url that you are 100% sure to be reliable. Also, how often is this code being ran? Would there be issue of writing to the same file path at the same time?

Comment: As far as I know, the server should be stable as it is working fine for everything else and I can access the file just fine through a browser. Even so, shouldn't an error be getting thrown if there was a server error?

Comment: You might need to catch the error. Try adding

.then(...).catch( error => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err)
})

Comment: Are you testing on a device or the emulators?  How is the internet connection?

There is an issue currently where the promise never resolves if the connection messes up.

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/239

Comment: @JoshuaLeonard I am testing on an Android device through USB cable and using adb over wifi. My Internet connection does seem to work fine for all other purposes, so not sure why that would be the problem. But the link you posted does seem to have similar symptoms so maybe there is some related issue.

Comment: Hey! Did you solve it? Maybe it's library problem?

Comment: @KeshaAntonov No, never did solve it. If you read my Update, I did find a work around, but not a very convenient.

Comment: @kojow7 I'll try to debug java code to see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be erroring silently. Try wrapping the whole block in a try/catch.

```
try {
  await RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: 'http://example.com/data/blah.zip',
    toFile: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/userdata/blah.zip",
  }).promise
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: I've tried both in a try..catch block and without one. The catch never invokes and it still just hangs. It seems to be intermittent however.

Comment: I assume thenifying it instead of async/await had no impact either?

Comment: No, it did not. Same effect.

Comment: I think it's time you setup a demo so we can poke around at it and see what the deal is

Comment: Unfortunately because it is intermittent, this problem is hard to diagnose or to create a demo. I have updated my question with a temporary solution, which is not very nice, but is effective.